# return unescaped html with jbuilder

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, jbuilder

I would like to return html content via jbuilder:

```
json.array!(@articles) do |article|
  json.extract! article, :id, :title, :html_content
end
```

But it's returns escaped html:

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "",
    "html_content": "\u003cp\u003e\u003cimg alt=\"\" src=\"#\" /\u003e\u003c/p\u003e\r\n"
}
```

How can it return unescaped html?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [html_safe](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-html_safe) to disable the escape feature. Probably you run into some problems, because `"` won't be escaped as well and it's in use to define a value in JSON.

I think the best approach is to encode it somehow, for example with `base64`:

- [Base64 encode in ruby](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html)
- [Base64 decode in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is to not retrieve the value via `extract!` I think this should do the trick.

```
json.array!(@articles) do |article|
  json.extract! article, :id, :title
  json.html_content article.html_content
end
```